# Alternatives to CSS n-th child selector in HTML table for Outlook

Tags: html, css, outlook, css-selectors, power-automate

using Power BI and Power Automate, I have created a flow smiliar to this tutorial (https://youtu.be/VnWg-Eox37Q) to send out my table as an html table in outlook.

The data itself is fine but now my problem is how to apply formatting to specific columns (for example the first 3 columns which are just dimension columns) should be left aligned instead of right and bigger column width, maybe even a line break.

The incoming data (rows) from Power-BI is dynamic and changing every interval.

But as far as I understood, Outlook is not supporting the n-th child selector in CSS you would use in this case. Do you know about any other easy work-arounds? Can't imaginge I am the first with this problem in Outlook.

Thank you for your time!

Edit #1: Added Code

So right now, considering I understood it correctly, it should font-align all column except the first 4 ones to the right. Works in an online tool like w3schools but not in Outlook.

```
<style>
table.table2 {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
table.table2 td, table.table2 th {
  border-left: none;
  border-right: none;
}
table.table2 tr td + td + td + td +td {
 text-align: right;
}
table.table2 tbody td {
  font-size: 13px;
  text-align: left;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #4A929E;
}
table.table2 thead {
  background: #4A929E;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
}
table.table2 thead th {
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-align: left;
  border-left: none;
}
table.table2 tfoot td {
  font-size: 13px;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Seems as though (what I thought was) a simpler set of selectors for the first 3 cells, tr + td, tr + td + td, tr + td + td + td, also doesn't work so you are likely to have to resort to inline styles.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah thats what I wanted to avoid since the html table is created dynamically through the "create html table" element in Power Automate. Do you, by chance, have any  ideas for a work-around?